# Use different layout in lazy loaded assembly

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I separated admin section of my Blazor WA app to own project. It's lazy loaded when user access the `/admin` page.
I followed [this](https://code-maze.com/lazy-loading-in-blazor-webassembly/) tutorial and everything works just fine. But when I want to **change layout** of my admin section, app just freezes (like the browser, no errors in console, no errors while debuging, nothing).

Structure of my `Admin` project:

[image]

This is what I have in `_Imports.razor`:

```
@layout AdminLayout
@using Admin.Shared
```

If I specify the layout for on page only, it works:

```
@page "/admin"
@layout AdminLayout
```

[Here](https://github.com/tesar-tech/BlazorLazyLoadingLayout) is the sample project.

What is wrong here? How can I have different layout in another project?

**EDIT**

After some investigation, it's clear that layout change has to be in `_Imports.razor` file, **that is located in Page folder**. It works that way!

Comment: Are you trying to set  a default layout in your _imports.razor file?

Comment: @NeilW yes, exactly. In the `_imports.razor` that is located in Admin project.

Comment: I don't think you can set default layout page in _imports.razor.  This should be set in App.razor file.

Comment: You need another new file in the Admin folder named `_Imports.razor` with 
`@layout AdminLayout` see https://blazor-university.com/layouts/using-layouts/

Comment: @DmitryPavlov Yes, exactly. That is something I tried yesterday, but it resulted in same error. Now it works (blazor magic or what...). I was thinking it's the same for imports in project..